# Dealing with text file containing list and None values

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a text file similar to this one:

```
a, 1, 2.5, 3
b, 1, 1, 1 1 2 3 4, 1 2, 3
c 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, None, 2
```

To put it in a nutshell each row starts with its name and is followed by a variable number of floats or list of floats delimited by commas and some float can be None values.
and I would like to parse it to get something similar to a dictionnary D

```
D['a']=[1,2.,3]
D['b']=[1,1,[1,1,2,3,4],[1,2],3]
D['c']=[1,2,2,2,2,None,2]
```

Basically I could have used `numpy.loadtxt` or `numpy.genfromtxt` and played with their options but there is not the same number of column in each row for genfromtxt or there are string values.
The csv module is helpful but still requires to do engineering on the resulting rows.
Do I need to use IO stream/csv and do that manually or is there some clean pythonic way of doing it ?
for now my ugly solution looks like this:

```
import csv
f=open("text.txt","rb")
reader=csv.reader(f)
D={}
for row in reader:
  if len(row)!=0:
    if row[0]=="a":
      D["a"]=row[1:]
    elif row[0]=="b":
```

and so on but now I have got to parse convert strings to number and list and floats.

**EDIT 1** With @Daniel Lee's answer and this poorly written hack it works but clearly I am not doing things right:

```
def convert list_to_float(L):
  s=[None]*len(L)       
  for index, l in enumerate(L):
    if len(l.split())>1:
        s[index]=[float(e) for e in l.split()]
    elif 'None' in l:
        s[index]=None
    else:
        s[index]=float(l)
  return s
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, D is a dictionary, then each row will use its 1st letter as the key and the rest of the list as the value.

```
import csv

with open('items.csv', 'rB') as f:
 csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
 for row in csv_reader:
     try:
         D[row[0]] = [float(x) for x in row[1:]]
     except ValueError as e:
         D[row[0]] = [float(f) for f in x.split() if f!='None' for x in row[1:]]
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: Exactly what I thought of!^^ except slightly more elegant but still a long way to go towards solution.

Comment: Do you need help splitting the string into ints? What must the dictionary contain if the element is None or a list or a float?

Comment: To convert the lists to floats lists you then need to parse each element of D with something like def convert_to_float(L): return [float(e) for e in L].

Comment: Still doing that you cannot deal with list of list.

Comment: L=['3','3 4 5','None'] must be [3,[3,4,5],None]

Comment: Can I pop the 'None' values?

Comment: No they need to be parsed as None but I am trying your solution but it still cannot handle '3 4 5' no?

Comment: Yeah your solution works but avoids problems instead of dealing with it!^^

Comment: Using .split() should give us the parsing of '3 4 5' and '3'  but not the None case

Comment: Using [float(e) for e in x.split() for x in L] breaks the structure